# AWS Lambda Couldn't load 'Argon2PasswordHasher' algorithm library

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using `Zappa` to deploy my backend application. I can login to the `/admin` normally while I am running local on `OSX 10.14.2`. Then I try deploy on `AWS Lambda`. Endpoint works fine. But `/admin/` returns to me

> Couldn't load 'Argon2PasswordHasher' algorithm library: /tmp/project-name/argon2/_ffi.abi3.so: invalid ELF header

I had followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416985/django-issue-with-argon2-hasher-in-live-production), but does not work. I have both of the dependencies according to [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django)

```
django[argon2]==2.2.2
argon2-cffi==19.1.0
zappa==0.48.2
```

I also check with `Django` issue. It has been solved 4 years [ago](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b4250ea04a88f6c4fdf84dc8624baa1cf3e0f568)

I have never not got this issue while I was working with `EC2` or any `VM` except `AWS Lambda` serverless

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from `AWS Support`. I need to deploy by using same `OS` and the host. Since I am using `OSX` then `C libraries` will not match the host. Change to `Linux` base. Then problem solved

Comment: Hi @Sarit How did you that?

Comment: You need to build zappa from dockerfile `lambci/lambda`. Install Zappa in global and dependencies in the virtualenv