# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argon2._ffi' in docker

Tags: python, docker

I faced strange issue in docker. Error is  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argon2._ffi'`
And my image with django inside it has this requirement satisfied. I found this [link](https://www.wolfssl.com/forums/topic867-solved-ffi-importerror-no-module-named-ffi.html) but there is too few info.

Maybe someone can elaborate, how to fix the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should elaborate, with enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've just started running into the exact same issue on a project that has been working for a very long time. I'm using pipenv and I have argon2-cffi locked to 19.1.0. I recently cleared all my docker volumes and containers then tried to run tests on this project and got the same issue you're facing. I'll post back if I find a solution...

Comment: I had an assumption, that the problem was not in fixing python version in docker. But I didn’t had a chance to test this idea.

Comment: I don't know why, but bumping from argon-cffi 19.1.0 to 19.2.0 worked for me. I don't have any explanation as to why. Maybe worth a shot though.

Comment: Can second that bumping the argon2-cffi version (in our case from 18.x to 21.3.0) fixed this as well! This may occur if you have an old build process that had been relying on cached base images, but the cache went down and the base images were updated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe installing Argon2 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55556957/7658051) solves your problem.

Try with:

```
python3 -m pip install argon2_cffi
python3 -m pip install -U cffi pip setuptools
```