# No module of _ffi found when create superuser

Tags: python, django, cffi

Python manage.py createsuperuser in django project in virtuelenv, reporting error: No module of _ffi found.

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO7GN.png)
[Error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArWuC.png)

I got some clue from google. for example update cffi and argon2, run python from different locations. But nothing works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to provide code-snippets.

Comment: What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using images which represent textual information. Instead, to the question paste the output as text. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a library which is missing in your environment. So if you have a `requirements.txt` file in your project try to run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I think it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119773/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-argon2-ffi-in-docker) one tbh.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anser. I have installed all dependencies. I googled and think this below thinking is right, but the suggested method does not work for me.  <if you run python inside wolfssl/wrapper/python it will try to use the local code instead of the installed one. the local code doesn’t have the _ffi module, it is built during the building process. The suggestion is to run python from a different location.>